# NullPointerException in Drools API

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, drools

I am getting null pointer exception while running the Java program.
`addPackageFromDrl` is not working properly and hence, pkg returned from `builder.getPackage()` is null.

I am using Drools 6

```
private static RuleBase readRules() throws DroolsParserException, IOException {
    Reader source = new InputStreamReader(   
    MessageDroolsTest1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "rule.drl" ) );

    System.out.println("Source:" + source);

    PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
    builder.addPackageFromDrl( source );
    System.out.println("Builder:" + builder);

    Package pkg = builder.getPackage();
    System.out.println("Package:" + pkg);

    RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
    ruleBase.addPackage( pkg );
    return ruleBase;            
}
```

I tried an alternate approach and still I am getting runtime exception.

```
private static KnowledgeBase createKnowledgeBase() {  
    KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();  
            //Add drl file into builder  
    File drl = new File("rules.drl");  
    builder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(drl), ResourceType.DRL);  
    if (builder.hasErrors()) {  
        throw new RuntimeException(builder.getErrors().toString());  
    }  

    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();  
            //Add to Knowledge Base packages from the builder which are actually the rules from the drl file.  
    knowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());  
    return knowledgeBase;  
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException:  
Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:  
java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
```

Comment: You aren't using the recommended build sequence for 6.x, see my addition. - Check that org/drools/compiler/rule/builder/dialect/java/JavaDialectConfiguration.class is in your 
drools-compiler-6.0.0.Final.jar on the class path. Check that you don't have a mixture of 5.x and 6-x jars on the class path-

Comment: @laune I installed the drools 6 jars and the above error is gone. I am getting this error now. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate service for Class 'org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService'` I did not see drools-api jar in drools 6.0, and hence copied from another project. Isn't drools-api jar available in drools 6? If not which jar should I include for KnowledgeBuilder?

Comment: It's in kie-internal-6.x.x.Final.jar. Put all jars from distribution into 1 directory. -A class path def sufficient in most cases: tag=6.0.0.Final; export CLASSPATH=".:$root/drools-core-${tag}.jar:$root/kie-api-${tag}.jar:$root/kie-internal-${tag}.jar:$root/knowledge-internal-api-${tag}.jar:$root/drools-compiler-${tag}.jar:$root/antlr-runtime-3.5.jar:$root/ecj-3.7.2.jar:$root/mvel2-2.1.7.Final.jar:/extra/quartz-1.8.3/quartz-1.8.3.jar:$root/drools-decisiontables-${tag}.jar:$root/drools-templates-${tag}.jar:$root/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:$root/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:$root/xstream-1.4.3.jar:$SLF4J"

Comment: @laune I added kie-internal import and eclipse is saying `KnowledgeBase` is deprecated.. Can't I use KnowledgeBase api's?

Comment: Thanks @laune, I made it tow work..

Comment: @cppcoder Hi, I'm having the same error as you did. I am using KnowledgeBase just as your updated code and I have included kie-api and kie-internal dependencies. However still the same error. How did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, at least with with a correct DRL file.

I suggest that you add

```
    System.out.println("Builder:" + builder);
    if( builder.hasErrors() ){
    System.out.println("Builder has errors!");
}
```

If this shows that there are errors, use other methods to retrieve the messages.

Drools 6 introduces a whole set of new classes (Knowledge*) and you should use that. Using the internal API (or what was used in Drools 5) is not recommended and your code may break with any release change.

** Later **

A simple build procedure for 6.x:

```
public void build() throws Exception {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "simple.drl" );
    kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.drl",
                kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) );
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
    if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
        System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
        throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
    }
    KieContainer kieContainer =
       kieServices.newKieContainer( kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );
    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
    kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
}
```

Comment: I tried `KnowledgeBuilder` way also. I am getting exception. Updated my question.